# Payflow checkout error on mobile "Invalid transaction type", works great on web

Tags: android, mobile, paypal, payflowlink

![After I enter all the CC info and press pay, this is the response from Payflow][1]

I have successfully used the page on web to make payments, but now when I want to make payments on a mobile device, I press the link to the payflow hosted checkout page, I fill in all the information (correctly) and when I press pay I get a red bar on top with the error "Invalid Transaction Type!"

Any help is appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Is there any website to check it ?

Comment: Yes! It's 

http://lauraimmigration.com/lawyer/Make-a-Payment_cp14227.htm

The case number can be left blank.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are passing "TYPE=s" instead of sending "TYPE=S" to PayPal. I tried passing "TYPE=S" and it worked for me in mobile browser too .